# Google Maps Api JSON can't read html_instructions

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I'm having trouble reading the html_instructions from the Google Maps Api json response, I suspect it's largely my lack of familiarity with dealing with Json objects but I can't seam to find the answer that would help me with this so here we go.

Following the Google directions service example I created a calcRoute function in javascript that posts a start and end location and receives a list of driving instructions in json format, it draws the route on the map all just fine. However when I want to list the driving instructions I can produce a list of steps containing distance and duration for each step but always return 'undefined' for the html_instructions. When I look at the json received each step has a html_instructions attribute with text, but i can't access it in code. Simple yes, so I thought, so what idiot thing am I missing?

```
function calcRoute() {    
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    try {
        var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: bowenSense,           
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL            
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                parseJson(response);
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);                
            }
            else {
                alert("Error: " + status);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (error) {
        alert("Error: " + error);
    };
}
function parseJson(response) {
    for (i = 0; i < response.routes.length; i++) {
        var route = response.routes[i];
        for (j = 0; j < route.legs.length; j++) {
            var leg = route.legs[j];
            // Do something with leg attributes...
            for (k = 0; k < leg.steps.length; k++) {
                var step = leg.steps[k];
                var distance = step.distance.text;    // fine
                var duration = step.duration.text;    // fine
                var instruction = step.html_instructions; // == undefined ?
                alert("instruction: " + instruction); 
                var mode = step.travel_mode;          // works
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Example JSON returned, showing populated html_instructions value

```
....
"steps" : [
              {
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "0.4 mi",
                    "value" : 695
                 },
                 "duration" : {
                    "text" : "1 min",
                    "value" : 61
                 },
                 "end_location" : {
                    "lat" : 53.3590723,
                    "lng" : -1.5065088
                 },
                 "html_instructions" : "Head \u003cb\u003ewest\u003c/b\u003e on \u003cb\u003eBannerdale Rd\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eNeedham Way\u003c/b\u003e",
                 "polyline" : {
                    "points" : "i~sdIjscHUvAi@vD[vAk@fC}@hDMf@[v@c@vAiA|Dy@dCuAzD[r@EJGLMXOTINQRUTYPSNOJQJSPOR"
                 },
                 "start_location" : {
                    "lat" : 53.3554115,
                    "lng" : -1.4983018
                 },
                 "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
              },
              ....
```

The puzzling thing is that both html_instruction and travel_mode are string values, one works the other doesn't, so is this an issue with the contents of the string? The html_instructions string has a lot of '\u****' (unicode?) encoded characters, wheras travel_mode is a plain old set of capitals?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, and thanks in advance.
ps I'm using most recent version of firefox browser if that matters.

Comment: response is text or JSON?

Comment: My map code uses `step.instructions` not `step.html_instructions`. I am using API v3 if that's any use. That's confirmed by the [API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference?hl=en#DirectionsStep).

Comment: can you tell which api you are using?

Comment: I should've said v3. Cheers Andy, I gave credit to Moazzam since he replied with an answer rather than a comment, you are both correct though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems when you use [URL](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Chicago,IL&destination=Los%20Angeles,CA&waypoints=Joplin,MO%7COklahoma%20City,OK&sensor=false) to get direction JSON, you get an `html_instructions` as a property of `step`, but using JS API's you get `instructions` as property of `step`.

Comment: Thanks that's fixed it, switching html_instructions for instructions. Kind of puzzling though if you look at the json snippet it clearly says html_instruction

Comment: How can we parse it with "Codable" protocol? I tried both html_instructions & instructions in my model that inherited from Codable protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Could you see what happens if you put `alert("instruction: " + step.html_instruction);`?

I've had lots of trouble getting JSON to work as I wanted it to whilst using google maps api before - it was a case of trying lots of different things that shouldn't make a difference until one did...

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer, it not html_instructions it instructions. change
 var instruction = step.html_instructions; // == undefined ?

to 
 var instruction = step.instructions;
it work perfectly on me, i don't know why 'html_instructions' became 'instructions'