# Missing HTML instructions from API request

Tags: google-maps, go

Why does the HTML instructions values get stripped out from the JSON decoding a Google Maps leg request?

Here is an unformatted snippet of the request body sent from a client using the Google Maps Javascript API, with HTML `instructions:` value intact.

```
steps: [{distance: {text: "85 ft", value: 26}, duration: {text: "1 min", value: 19},…},…]
0: {distance: {text: "85 ft", value: 26}, duration: {text: "1 min", value: 19},…}
distance: {text: "85 ft", value: 26}
duration: {text: "1 min", value: 19}
encoded_lat_lngs: "sfnhFhuljOEx@"
end_location: {lat: 38.2527656, lng: -85.7587412}
end_point: {lat: 38.2527656, lng: -85.7587412}
instructions: "Head <b>west</b> toward <b>W Liberty St</b>"
```

The following is the code for decoding the request.

```
package main 

import (
   "net/http"
   "encoding/json"
   "fmt"
    "github.com/kr/pretty"
    "googlemaps.github.io/maps"
)

type LegRequest struct {
    Leg []maps.Leg `json:"legs"`
}

func legHandler(
    w http.ResponseWriter,
    r *http.Request,
) {
    // Set CORS headers for the preflight request
    if r.Method == http.MethodOptions {
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNoContent)
        return
    }
    // Set CORS headers for the main request.
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    var input LegRequest
    defer r.Body.Close()
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&input)
    r.ParseForm()
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
    }
    pretty.Println(input)
    fmt.Fprint(w, input)
}

func Server() {
    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
        port = "8080"
        log.Printf("Defaulting to port %s", port)
    }
    http.HandleFunc("/leg", legHandler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, nil))
}
```

Result snippet from a random step in one of the result legs:

```
                &maps.Step{
                    HTMLInstructions: "",
                    Distance:         maps.Distance{HumanReadable:"0.1 mi", Meters:191},
                    Duration:         146000000000,
                    StartLocation:    maps.LatLng{Lat:39.096503, Lng:-84.5101873},
                    EndLocation:      maps.LatLng{Lat:39.0982251, Lng:-84.5105605},
                    Polyline:         maps.Polyline{Points:"c`smFt{xbOIIECKG[FOFILM@i@HaAPw@LUDo@JOB"},
                    Steps:            nil,
                    TransitDetails:   (*maps.TransitDetails)(nil),
                    TravelMode:       "WALKING",
                },
```

This behaviour seem consistent in various results. I plan to include more variables in the HTTP request later, so I have not attempted the `UnMarshalJSON` method for `maps.Leg` type on the response body.

From the API reference on Google maps Go client library I find

```
type Step struct {
    // HTMLInstructions contains formatted instructions for this step, presented as an
    // HTML text string.
    HTMLInstructions string `json:"html_instructions"`
```

Note the `html_instructions` JSON key, whereas the Javascript API uses `instructions` as key for the HTML instructions. Can this be the cause of the values being left out?

Comment: Probably related [Google Maps Api JSON can't read html_instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636301/google-maps-api-json-cant-read-html-instructions).

Comment: Yes, the question was regarding the same problem, thanks. However, my issue is that the Go Google maps client library uses the `html_instructions` key for the `Step` type. I have tried to write a custom type struct for decoding the bytes to `&input` from the http request, but only got garble.

Comment: To cite from the answer of the other question: *"It seems when you use URL to get direction JSON, you get an html_instructions as a property of step, but using JS API's you get instructions as property of step"*. And it seems to me that you are using the JS API. Only an actual browser needs these `Access-Control-*` headers.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich yes I do believe I have to use the JS API for my purpose. Thanks for pointing out the CORS stuff, I am using those in my local test environment, accessing the Go API from a Maps JS API client in a local browser (webpack dev server).

Comment: Meanwhile, I will extract the HTML instructions from the result Leg, and pass along as a HTTP request body parameter. Then insert them back in the steps in the Go API.